# How can I get matching curly double quotes using listings?

Tags: listings, punctuation

I'm having a strange problem with listings. I'm trying to use matching double quotes around strings, as in this minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
    language=Java,
    tabsize=2,
    numbers=left,
    basicstyle=\footnotesize
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
void my_method() {
    int test = 0;
    some_method(``string");
    boolean b = false;
    some_method(``string");

}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

First of all, the backticks render individually instead of as a nice curly left double quote like I want. And, well, the bigger problem is that after inserting the backticks it starts showing all the whitespace in my code in between the two strings, even when I add showspaces=false to my settings, as in the following screenshot:

[image: result of the above markup]

I've found a lot about how to use straight double quotes, but I actually do want the curly quotes. Does anyone know how I can insert the left quotation marks properly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the curly left quotes with literate, but imho you have to disable the string delimiter to avoid to get the spaces shown.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
    language=Java,
    tabsize=2,
    numbers=left,
    basicstyle=\footnotesize,
    literate={``}{\textquotedblleft}1,
    deletestring=[b]",
    ,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
void my_method() {
    int test = 0;
    some_method(``string");
    boolean b = false;
    some_method(``string");

}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hmm, it seems it has two single left quotes, rather than a double left quote.

Comment: @egreg, you are right, one has to use \textquotedblleft

Comment: I wish I could accept both answers, since it was really just the literate thing I was looking for. I went with something like this, used `''` instead of `"`, and added `{''}{\textquotedblright}1` to the arguments for literate.

Answer (score 1):

`listings` scans character by character, so you have to teach it not do do this in special cases:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
  language=Java,
  tabsize=2,
  numbers=left,
  basicstyle=\footnotesize,
  literate=
    {``}{\odblq}{1}
    {''}{\cdblq}{1},
}
\newcommand{\odblq}{``}
\newcommand{\cdblq}{''}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
void my_method() {
    int test = 0;
    some_method(``string'');
    boolean b = false;
    some_method(``string'');

}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Using `''` for the closing quotes avoids the problem with `"` being considered a delimiter.

However, this might confuse your readers, who could think that reverse quotes are needed in their code.

An alternative could be using UTF-8

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
  language=Java,
  tabsize=2,
  numbers=left,
  basicstyle=\footnotesize,
  literate=
    {“}{\odblq}{1}
    {”}{\cdblq}{1},
}
\newcommand{\odblq}{``}
\newcommand{\cdblq}{''}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
void my_method() {
    int test = 0;
    some_method(“string”);
    boolean b = false;
    some_method(“string”);

}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your two solutions solved the problem with quotation marks (I prefer the last one because I need `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` in my full document), but if I have defined a `stringstyle=\bfseries\color{blue},` this doesn't work properly (I mean the quotation marks works fine but inside `“example”` the word `example` doesn't painted blue). Do you need an MWE in a new question?

Comment: Please see this [example](https://imgur.com/a/ypjDNtc).

Comment: @egreg; nice suggestion...