# Using stringstyle with quotation marks does not fit properly using listings package

Tags: listings, punctuation, copy-paste

Please consider this MWE with `stringstyle=\bfseries\color{blue}`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{listings}

\definecolor{codegreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{codegray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{codepurple}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{backcolour}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.92}

\lstset {%
    backgroundcolor=\color{backcolour},
    commentstyle=\color{codegreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{magenta},
        stringstyle=\bfseries\color{blue},      % <-- When using it the style does not apply because of ""
    basicstyle=\scriptsize,
    breakatwhitespace=false,
    breaklines=true,
    captionpos=b,
    keepspaces=true,
    numbers=left,
    numbersep=5pt,
    showspaces=false,
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,
    tabsize=2,
    keepspaces=true,
    language=C++,
    columns=flexible,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
"Example"
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

It is well known that the double quotation marks does not fit properly:

[image: Quotation marks error]

So I researched and I came across the two fantastic solutions that [Ulrike Fischer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/320453/how-can-i-get-matching-curly-double-quotes-using-listings/320457#320457) and [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/320458/152550) propose *in the same question!*

Unfortunately, if I add any of the two solutions, two things happen:

1. **The style** of quotation marks **and** the text inside it does not shown: [image: Without style]
2. When I tried to copy that output it gaves me, for example using egreg second answer: **“Example”** (not **"Example"**). This is bad because in a compiler the first two characters *“”* make the code not compile correctly: [image: Bad quotation marks]

*In fact, if it is also possible that in the `PDF` output the double quotes appear in the same way as after copying them as I want.*

Is there an easy way to solve these two problems?

Thank you!!

**P.S:** [Thank you to cfr](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/442676/152550) I forgot to mention that I use `LaTeX->PS->PDF` and, if I add `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` then all the text inside it dissappear. Try adding that and test with more lines of code:

```
\begin{lstlisting}
"Example"

Code around here


and here
\end{lstlisting}
```

the output is:

[image: Error]

and here is the Build Output:

[image: Build Output]

Comment: I really think this is confusing to readers. If they need to type straight quotes in their code, the sample code should use straight quotes. If I see curly quotes in a code listing, I assume that I need curly quotes in my code.

Comment: Or are you asking how to get straight quotes?

Comment: @cfr for that I added the italic text: *In fact, if it is also possible that in the PDF output the double quotes appear in the same way as after copying them as I want.* I mean: if in the PDF we show that "Example" then in the compiler we need to use " " **(using the same style of quotes)**. But I don't know how to modify it `:(`.

Comment: Btw remember that there are another problem (the style is not shown in the `PDF` output).

Comment: I don't understand the problem about the style. What style isn't shown? It looks OK to me. What am I supposed to be looking at?

Comment: @cfr I use `pdfLaTeX`, `TeXnicCenter` and `LaTeX->PS->PDF` output. I think the first is that causes the problem.

Comment: So you're not using pdfLaTeX or you are? pdfLaTeX produces PDF directly - no PS. That's how I got the output below. Otherwise, LaTeX would produce DVI. I don't know how to get PS direct from a `.tex` file. (Not saying you're not - just I've never done this and have no idea how to do it.)

Comment: Sorry... I don't understand at all this properties `:/`. I use `LaTeX->PS->PDF`. If you need another info. please indicate me how to show you that.

Comment: I get the same output from my code with `pdflatex` or with `latex` -> `dvipdf` or with `latex` -> `dvips` -> `ps2pdf`.

Comment: I don't know how to produce postscript output directly from a `.tex` file. I can do it by running `latex` and geting DVI and then converting to PS and then converting that to PDF. But the output is the same in all cases.

Comment: **You are NOT using pdfLaTeX.** Also, it isn't clear if the problem you're describing occurs when you compile **precisely my code** or something else.

Comment: Anyway, try adding `\usepackage{lmodern}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need the `T1` output encoding for fonts. (Note that this assumes one of the traditional TeX engines i.e. TeX or pdfTeX.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor,textcomp}
\usepackage{listings}

\definecolor{codegreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{codegray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{codepurple}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{backcolour}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.92}

\lstset {%
    backgroundcolor=\color{backcolour},
    commentstyle=\color{codegreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{magenta},
        stringstyle=\bfseries\color{blue},      % <-- When using it the style does not apply because of ""
    basicstyle=\scriptsize,
    breakatwhitespace=false,
    breaklines=true,
    captionpos=b,
    keepspaces=true,
    numbers=left,
    numbersep=5pt,
    showspaces=false,
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,
    tabsize=2,
    keepspaces=true,
    language=C++,
    columns=flexible,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
"Example"  "Example"
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

The second "Example" is copied back from the PDF rendered in Okular.

[image: straight up]

Note that this depends on the fonts you use in the document being available in the T1 encoding. For most people,

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

is all that's needed. This is true for anybody with a full version of TeX Live installed, for example.

If, however, you do not have Computer Modern available in the T1 format, you may get errors from pdfTeX or from the binary used to convert from DVI. In this case, either install the missing fonts (e.g. `cm-super` is one package providing CM in T1 format) or switch font packages (e.g. load `lmodern` or, better yet, obviously, `cfr-lm`).

Comment: Ah yes, I tried that but **all the code inside `listings` environment is not shown**. I forgot to mention that.

Comment: @manooooh Can you please copy my code into a new `.tex` file and compile it using `pdflatex`? Do you then get the output I show?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The `PDF` does not shown anything. I will edite my answer right now.

Comment: Then please add `\listfiles` to the top of the file, compile and post the `.log`.

Comment: *Off-topic*: You are god! All that had to be done was add `\usepackage{lmodern}`. I think you should edit your answer with this. The times that I compile my code using only `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` was very frustrating because I see examples on Internet working fine, but with the first package problem solved!

Comment: @manooooh `lmodern` is not necessary. Only the `T1` encoding is. But you do not have Computer Modern installed in the T1 encoding, so, although your DVI is fine, your PDF is not. However, most people do have CM installed in the T1 encoding, so `lmodern` is not necessary. (I like `lmodern`, but that's a different matter.) Note that if you have on-the-fly installation enabled, MikTeX should install it automatically - at least if you use pdfTeX rather than TeX. If you stick to TeX, you can always install `cm-super` in the package manager.

Comment: You said "If you stick to `TeX`". Am I using `TeX`? I thought all this time I was using `LaTeX`...

Comment: I've added a note. TeX is the engine. LaTeX is the format. I mean: you are using TeX as opposed to pdfTeX. On the command line, you're using `latex` rather than `pdflatex`.

Comment: Your help is greatly appreciated and the note is fine. Hm... that leads me to think that I'm doing things quite badly, even if I get some "nice" documents with the help of you (is it possible that by how everything is set on my PC the accents that I copy from the `PDF` to another side, I see something like `'a` instead of `á`?)

Comment: I believe that inside my computer explosions occur every time I compile 100 lines of code while in yours everything is perfect *ouch :(*.

Comment: Oh, that's because you're not using T1, too. 'á' doesn't occur in the default encoding, so TeX creates it from two characters, which is what you see when you copy. But if you use T1, a real 'á' is used, which should copy fine. This is because, when TeX was written, fonts could have only 128 characters. T1 has 256, so it deals much better with most accented characters. (Although something like 'tŷ' will unfortunately still not copy correctly. :()

Comment: When I use XeTeX or `titlesec`, there are explosions everywhere.

Comment: Take note that I will never use 'tŷ' hahaha (I am Argentinian). Ok, so I will add that package. Anyway, I don't know why I have in my code `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` and `\usepackage[spanish]{babel}`. In most of times these 3 packages are needed?

Comment: You make me feel better with that `:)`. But if you use it to test and not to produce important documents it's not worth it!

Comment: Depends which bit of Argentina. Argentina is the one other place in the world where somebody might want 'tŷ' natively :-). And yes, you want all three packages: `inputenc` for input (the `utf8` should match the encoding you save your `.tex` file in), `babel` for anything except US English (even for UK English, you need it) and `fontenc` for T1 output encoding (generally, certainly for Spanish).

Comment: Yes, I do not use `titlesec` of XeTeX for production documents. Always pdfLaTeX and something-which-is-not-`titlesec`. (I should say, everyone else gets on great with `titlesec`. Just I'm allergic, I think.)

Comment: please see [When my mom sees this she will not understand anything](https://imgur.com/a/Q1qdqHE) `:D`. I will remember your suggestions

Comment: Hmmm ... I didn't say don't use `lmodern`. I don't. I use `cfr-lm`. (If I was happy with `lmodern`, I wouldn't have written `cfr-lm`.) But `lmodern` is fine if you're happy with the default choices it imposes.

Comment: Also, `cfr-lm` depends on `lmodern`. All the actual fonts are from `lmodern` and so is everything mathematical. So is the `microtype` config.

Comment: How could I run these in Windows 10 using `TeXnicCenter`?: `$ apt-get install cm-super`

Comment: That command is for a Debian-based Linux system with Debian-packaged TeX Live. (And it won't work as written anyway unless something is very wrong with the system.) Use MikTeX's package manager to install packages. The Latin Modern fonts are better, in my opinion. But that's just my opinion and not a universal view.

Comment: Thank you! I am downloading that package (it run slowly with `~200 KB/Sec` `:S`). Clarify this: if I install this and use `\usepackage{cfr-lm}` or `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` the accents, etc. can be copied correctly from `PDF` output on any computer?

Comment: If you install `cm-super`, `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` should be sufficient. This will then use Computer Modern in the T1 encoding. If you want to use Latin Modern instead, you don't need `cm-super`. In that case, either use `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}\usepackage{lmodern}` or use `\usepackage[<options if you want>]{cfr-lm}`, depending on whether you are OK with `lmodern`'s choices or not. `lmodern` uses tabular, lining numbers throughout, which I don't like. `cfr-lm` lets you choose the numbers you want and the typewriter font and so on. `texdoc cfr-lm` for details.